# getBlob() returning unexpected bytes and database column datatype getting changed automatically

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a pre-populated SQLite database having two tables :

> Table 1 : AudioSamples (_id text primary key,AudioFile blob)
>
> ```
>           where _id --> name of the audio file 
>           AudioFile --> audio file (.PCM file)
> ```
>
> Table 2 : android_metadata(locale text)
>
> ```
>           where locale --> 'en_US'
> ```

what I do is :

1. I put this table to android assets folder and then my app copies it to system database when app is started for first time.
2. I access the blob field 'AudioFile' using getBlob() function which returns me byte array.
3. When I write contents of byte array to AudioTrack object, i can hear my audio file but with lot of noise.

The problem is :

1. When I pulled my database from System database folder to my PC and checked datatype of column 'AudioFile', its giving me type 'text' instead of 'blob'.
2. getBlob() is returning more bytes than expected.

My Audio playback code is working fine for other pcm files.

Code to insert .pcm files :

```
private static void insertFile(char FileName){
        String filepath="C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/imp files/"+FileName+".pcm";
        try{
            PreparedStatement pstmt=c.prepareStatement("insert into AudioSamples values(?,?)");
            File f=new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
            byte[] buff=new byte[(int)f.length()];
            fin.read(buff);

            pstmt.setString(1,String.valueOf(FileName));
            pstmt.setBytes(2,buff);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.clearParameters();
            fin.close();
            System.out.println("Inserted file :"+FileName+".pcm size="+(buff.length/1024)+"KB");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.print("Error :"+e);
        }
    }
```

I checked my table data before putting it in assets using code :

```
private static void GetTableData(String TableName){

        try{
            Statement stmt=c.createStatement();
            String myquery="select * from "+TableName;
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(myquery);

            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("For "+rs.getString("_id")+".pcm :");
                System.out.println("size="+rs.getBytes(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(2)).length/1024+"KB");
                System.out.println("column1 name:"+rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(1));
                System.out.println("column1 type:"+rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(1));
                System.out.println("column2 name:"+rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(2));
                System.out.println("column2 type:"+rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(2));
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("GetTableData()"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Which was giving me expected results in log as  :

> For a.pcm : size=27KB
>
> column1 name:_id
>
> column1 type:12
>
> column2 name:AudioFile
>
> column2 type:2004

Code for copying database file 'AudioData.db' in assets to System database:

```
private void copyDatabase() throws IOException{
        //stream to read database in assets folder
        InputStream ipstream = myContext.getAssets().open("AudioData.db");

        //stream to write to empty database in system folder
        FileOutputStream opstream= new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);

        byte[] buff=new byte[1024*512];  //create 512Kb buffer
        int bytesRead=0;
        while((bytesRead=ipstream.read(buff))!=(-1)){
            opstream.write(buff, 0, bytesRead); //write to empty db in systems folder
        }
        Log.v(DB_NAME,"Database copied");

        //close streams
        opstream.flush();
        opstream.close();
        ipstream.close();
        Log.v("myDataBase status",""+(myDataBase!=null));
    }
```

Here's my code for accessing pcm files :

```
 public byte[] getPCMFile(String FileName){
            Cursor cursor=null; 
            byte[] buff = null;

            try{
                cursor=myDataBase.query("AudioSamples",null,"_id=?",new String[]{FileName},null, null,null);
                Log.v("getPCMFile()","Obtained table has Column  count="+cursor.getColumnCount());  
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                Log.v(FileName+".pcm", "_id columntype="+cursor.getType(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                Log.v(FileName+".pcm", "AudioFile columntype="+cursor.getType(cursor.getColumnIndex("AudioFile")));
                buff=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("AudioFile"));
                Log.v("getPCMFile()","Blob retrived :"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))+".pcm size="+buff.length);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("getPCMFile()","Couldnt read PCM file "+FileName+".pcm", e);
            }       

            cursor.close();
            return buff;    //return byte array containing pcm samples
        }
```

for getPCMFile('a') ,it is giving me log as :

> Obtained table has Column count=2
>
> AudioFile columntype=3
>
> _id columntype=3
>
> Blob retrived :a.pcm size=49046

AudioFile columntype should be 2004 (for blob) and actual size of a.pcm is 27124 but it is retriving 49046 byes. 
Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you copying the database? How do you determine the database is correct before copying?

Comment: @laalto: I have edited my question and added the code which i have used for checking and copying database.

Comment: `setBytes()` likely treats the arg not as a blob. Try `setBlob()` instead.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it is not supported by the driver.I tried to search for other drivers but couldnt get one.Anyways,I will try one more time. Thanks for reply!

Comment: @laalto : I tried but no sqlite driver supports setBlob() method! Also  the setBytes method  causing the column datatype to change from blob to varchar!!! I am surprised there is not even single java driver for sqlite supporting blob method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is not prefered in android to store your audio files in your database .

and use the assest folder instaed to store your audio files .

save your audio files in the assest folder and thier related information in the database .

Hope that helps

Comment: Ya I know but here I will need database to store other attributes of audio files in future.By the ways, the audio files here are very small (~ 30KB).

Comment: Actually, i will be performing some signal analysis on each audio file later.The analysis will give me different properties of each audio file(like zero crossings, FFT etc). How can I store such information in assets folder? Since I am going to search audio file by matching those attributes, wouldn't it be faster to access through pre-populated database?

Comment: i am telling you to store the audio files in the assest , but your information about these audio files should be stored in your database , wehre you can update as you want later on , when you do your signal analysis .

Comment: Yes that can be one way, but can you please help me regarding above code? Thanks for replying!

Comment: what code you mean ? and please accept my answer , and vote up :)

Comment: I mean my above problem,as given in question heading.Files can be surely accessed from assets folder but this is not answer to my question!

Comment: ok you want to know how to acces audio files in your assest folder ?

Comment: I don't want to put my files in assets folder but rather access from database itself since they are very small in size. So please if you can tell me where I am getting wrong in above question, I would appreciate it!

Comment: please tell me waht are you using to save the images to the sqlite database before using it in your application , what tool you ARE using ?

Comment: I have .pcm audio files in my PC which i am storing in database using PreparedStatement query in java.

Comment: could you please post your java code that inserts the audio file ?